# Run an AppleScript for an email message with keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, email, applescript, ui-automation, omnifocus

I need to run one of a few Applescripts on some email messages at my discretion (no automation). If I could run them with keyboard shortcut that would be great if not right click will work too.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think what you want is either a Service or a QuickAction — both of which you make through Automator — but it depends on what *kind* of applescripts these are. What do they do? Or at least, what kind of input do they take? I know you can attach keyboard shortcuts to Services; I'm not sure about QuickActions, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate in another forum https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote